# CSS Grid make all rows min-height and one of them span the rest

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with 5 rows. The third row's content height varies depending on the content. First and last two rows have fixed height content. My problem is, when the content of third row is larger in one of the grid containers, the difference in other grid containers is spread across the grid and my content in first, second, fourth, and fifth rows looks misaligned. I tried assigning `align-self` for those but it didn't work. How can I achieve a consistent look regardless of the content of the middle row?

I cannot give a fixed height value for the third row.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

The example code:
https://codepen.io/samet-m-tevelli/pen/NWYVQey

Comment: I see the problem in the image you posted. But the layout in your code looks fine (when tested in Chrome).

Comment: You probably saw it after I implemented my solution on the same codepen.

Comment: That's why you should put the code in the question itself. This post is no longer useful because the code doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Reverted the codepen to its original state. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Make it one grid, that way the system knows how to adjust the heights.

And make the 4 outer items take up any free space and the middle third one to be sized auto:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  gap: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child1,
.child2,
.child3,
.child4,
.child5 {
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child2">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child3">
      Okay<br /> Okay
      <br />

    </div>
    <div class="child4">Hey</div>
    <div class="child5">Ho</div>
    <div class="child1">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child2">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child3">
      Okay<br /> Okay
      <br /> Okay
      <br />

    </div>
    <div class="child4">Hey</div>
    <div class="child5">Ho</div>
    <div class="child1">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child2">Yeah</div>
    <div class="child3">
      Okay<br /> Okay
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="child4">Hey</div>
    <div class="child5">Ho</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually came up with the same solution but instead of using 1fr in `grid-template-rows` I used `min-content` because all those rows except the middle one has different size heights and they are all consistent except the middle one. So I'll accept your answer since it gives the correct idea.

Comment: My solution:   `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content) auto repeat(2, min-content);`